# Is it possible to define classes with same name in same namespace but in different nested projects?

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, eclipse-cdt

I have one big project in Eclipse, which contains multiple nested projects. Each one of those nested projects is in a separate folder and is compiled and linked separately. At the end, each one of them outputs a separate static library. Then there are few executables which are linked against those static libraries. In two of these projects I have two classes with the same name and same constructor arguments, but they have different implementations and also different extra members. Both classes are in the same namespace. After I compile each project I use the static libraries which they have created for a separate executables. Each executable is linked against the correct class, they don't mix implementations. Everything seems to work fine.

The problem is that when I compile one of the classes, the compiler gives me an error that I haven't initialized some member variables, which actually belong to the other class. During compilation those classes don't have an access to each other - they don't include the other one or they don't include headers, which then include the other one. They are in separate projects, in separate folders and are compiled separately. How is then possible that when compiling the first class the compiler somehow looks for the definition of the second class and gives me an error that I haven't initialized a member from it? Since I am using Eclipse and my projects' structure is like this: Main C++ Project (which is not compiled) holds the other C++ projects as nested projects (which are compiled separately) inside it - is it possible that this is something related to Eclipse?

Am I violating the One Definition Rule, since my classes are in separate projects and they are compiled in separate compilations, only having some common header files and no other connection between them? And if so, how is it possible that the compiler catches such an issue but it is still able to get the correct class definition? Because for sure it gets it right and everything works fine.

So my problem is the warning that the compiler gives me, because I have to clean all compilation warning before shipping the code. The code itself works fine.

Best Regards

=== Update After Comments ===

First of all, apologies for not being clear. 
Here is an image of the whole Project structure (I have changed the names obviously :) ):

[The structure of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NO6if.png)

I have the MainProject project, which acts as a container for the other projects. I don't build it. In **nested1** I have projects which make static libraries, which I then link with the Executable1 and Executable2. In **nested2** I have other projects which again make static libraries, which I then link with the Executable3.

I have the MyFooBar class in both nested1 and nested2. Here is the code for both of them

```cpp
// nested1/StaticLib5/MyFooBar.hpp
namespace foo
{
    namespace bar
    {
        class MyFooBar : public FooBar
        {
            public:
                   MyFooBar(int a, int b, double c);
                   // Getters and Setters
                   // Other user-defined functions
            private:
                   int memA;
                   int memB;
                   double memC;
                   int memDiff1;
        };
    }
}
```

```cpp
// nested2/StaticLib9/MyFooBar.hpp
namespace foo
{
    namespace bar
    {
        class MyFooBar : public FooBar
        {
            public:
                   MyFooBar(int a, int b, double c);
                   // Getters and Setters
                   // Other user-defined functions
            private:
                   int memA;
                   int memB;
                   double memC;
                   int memDiff2;
                   char memDiff3;

        };
    }
}
```

```cpp
// nested1/StaticLib5/MyFooBar.cpp
namespace foo
{
    namespace bar
    {
        MyFooBar::MyFooBar(int a, int b, double c) :
        memA{a}, memB{b}, memC{c}, memDiff1{0}
        {
        }         
    }
}
```

```cpp
// nested2/StaticLib9/MyFooBar.cpp
namespace foo
{
    namespace bar
    {
        MyFooBar::MyFooBar(int a, int b, double c) :
        memA{a}, memB{b}, memC{c}, memDiff2{0}, memDiff3{0}
        {
        }         
    }
}
```

Executable1 and Executable2 don't use any of the libraries in **nested2**. Executable3 uses the only the static library StaticLib1 **nested1**.

Non of the Executables is linked to both StaticLib5 and StaticLib9. Also, I don't get an error during the linking of the executables, I get warning when compiling any of the MyFooBar classes. The warning says:

```
Member memDiff2 was not initialized in this constructor
```

The only thing that might be common for both classes is one header, where I have a class forward declaration and some typedefs, which I don't use in the class itself.

```cpp
class MyFooBar;
typedef ListWidget* MyFooBarPtr;
typedef std::vector< MyFooBarPtr > MyFooBarVec;
typedef MyFooBarVec* MyFooBarVecPtr;
```

Comment: Too much text. No code. That makes for a poor question.

Comment: Two classes with the same name in the same namespace will collide when linking occurs, yes.

Comment: Why this works now, is based on many variables specific to Your project. One day it can stop working. So You better fix it.

Comment: @RSahu: I Added example code.

Comment: @Chad: I don't link against both of them at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thanks for your help. The issue seems to be with the QNX Momentics IDE itself. If I build the projects from the command line no warnings are printed. If I build the first MyFooBar from **nested1** then one project from **nested2** then the second MyFooBar from **nested2** I am given this warning. If I build the first MyFooBar then several other projects from **nested1** then the second MyFooBar, there are no such warnings. In either cases, the build is fine and everything works as expected.

Best Regards,
Ahmed

Answer (score 0):

There is one definition rule in C++ that you cannot have classes/functions defined twice. Not to mention the case when definitions are different.

That's being said, there are also isolation rules that allows you to bypass the one definition rule. Say, you have two classes with same name but they are defined and used only in two different .cpp files then everything should work...

**Update:** it might compile but it will do so because linker does a poor job of it. It won't work properly if definitions don't match. But it does work when you have project level separation, i.e., in different shared library files aka .dll - dynamic library level separation required, .cpp or static libraries separation level is not sufficient. Thx to @fdan and @FrancisCugler.

Basically, as long as there any projects that use both definitions somehow - lest there is a strong compilation boundary - it is a violation of one definition rule and cannot properly compile.

P.S. why even have two classes with identical name? This is an excellent source of bugs. If you want to have portable code between different architectures or OS systems, you can use #ifdef to remove the non-suitable version of the class from build.

Comment: "Say, you have two classes with same name but they are defined and used only in two different .cpp files then everything should work." - I strongly disagree.

Comment: It does matter because when the compiler tries to look up the name of that class's constructor's declaration and definition it will choose one of the two but there is no guarantee that it will choose the correct one. There is still a naming conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider what the compiler does behind the scenes: We have two modules or translation units: Module A and B.

During compilation we would have the following:

```
Module A: namespace::class_name == foo::bar 
Module B: namespace::class_name == foo::bar
```

During compilation of source code into object files these will compile fine separately as you have stated. The issue here isn't with the compiler.

The problem arises when it takes all of the object code or translation units and tries to link everything together to build a single executable.

This is when you end up having naming or symbol resolution conflicts which does violate the one definition rule. It is within the linker that problems arise.

However some compilers that are built within an integrated development environment such as Visual Studio may have some compiler flags that will "look ahead" so to speak to see if any possible conflicts may occur before compilation is done and this can generate compile time warnings or even errors before you even make it to the linker.

I would suggest either changing the class's name or the namespace name, however it would be more convenient to keep the namespace name over the class's name since that is the name space that represents your code base.

If for some reason you need to keep the class as the same name, then their may be one other alternative and that is to include a middle internal nested namespace name to resolve this conflict of naming to reduce ambiguity.

For example:

```
Module A: namespace::namespace::class_name = foo::ver_1::bar
Module B: namespace::namespace::class_name = foo::ver_2::bar
```

Then the interior nested namespace would prevent this naming conflict as long as you are not using directives such as:

```
#using namespace foo::ver_1;
#using namespace foo::ver_2;
```

Within the same visible scope!